# Search By Regex Pattern ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, activerecord

Is there a way to search via Regex pattern in ActiveRecord? I have a collection of products. I'll like to search these products based on their sku column meeting a number of patterns.

SKUs having single letters from [A-Z] should be considered `premium products`
SKUs having single letters [A-Z] and a digit[0-9] should be considered `standard products`
SKUs having double letters and a digit [0-9] should be considered `flash products`

Here is a pseudo-code of what I need:

```
product.sku ~= /[A-Z]$/  => Premium Products
product.sku ~= /[A-Z][0-9]$/ => Standard Products
product.sku ~= /[A-Z]{2}[0-9]$/ => Flash products
```

I don't want to use ruby's `select` filtering. Is this possible via active-record?

Comment: What database do you use? Postgresql, SQLIite, MySQL?

Comment: _“Is this possible via active-record?“_ — yes, this is possible if you are using the DB that supports fuzzy searches.

Comment: I'm using postgres as DB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you using a database that supports regex matching, this is possible. E.g: Postgres. I have done some regex search on ActiveRecord using Postgres as DB. You can read up this [article](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html)

So in your case, you can simply do:

```
premium_products = Product.where("sku ~ ?", '[A-Z]$')
standard_products = Product.where("sku ~ ?", '[A-Z][0-9]$')
flash_products = Product.where("sku ~ ?", '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]$')
```